# Code Coverage for ASP.NET/C# webapp in Mono Framework

Tags: asp.net

I'm developing a webapp using ASP.NET and C# in Mono Framework. And I developed a automated testing using NUnit and selenium. My question is, how can I integrate a code coverage testing for my web app?

Please advise.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look here:

[MonoCov](http://www.mono-project.com/Code_Coverage)